# System-wide sound effects on OS X?

Tags: audio

Is there an option in macOS which would allow a 3rd party to install a system-wide sound effect on an macOS machine? Something similar to [Windows APO](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/audio/audio-processing-object-architecture) (Audio Processing Object) technology:

"*Windows allows OEMs and third-party audio hardware manufacturers to include custom digital signal processing effects as part of their audio driver's value-added features. These effects are packaged as user-mode system effect Audio Processing Objects (APOs).*"

The technology enables users to easily enable/disable system-wide sound enhancement algorithms (see screenshot).

From the system tray:

[image: Enabling system wide sound enhancement algorithms in Windows 10.]

From the device settings:

[image]

Comment: Could you add to your question what this kind of software offers to macOS users, how it is used, what apps could benefit, etc.

Comment: Added some info and screenshots.

Comment: OK, no. As explained in my answer, you cannot plug straight in at system-level. You need an app that will bridge the two. Look at SoundSource to see how that's implemented (at least as far as the user can see it)

Answer (score 1):

You can add [Audio Unit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/audiounit) effects, which can be used by any AU-capable audio app. Example with Apple originals & third party additions…

[image]

Generally, you cannot plug these directly into the Mac's audio output, you need an app capable of accessing them. Apps such as [SoundSource](https://rogueamoeba.com/soundsource/) can do this for any app or all, at simple general consumer level, intercepting between app or system output & the intended hardware out.

There is, of course, already a large market for these effects as stand-alone processors, in the pro audio world. From free to expensive.
If you search "VST plugins" you'll find many of these that come in multi-format, VST, AU, etc. [VST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Studio_Technology) is a proprietary format from Steinberg, but the plugin API is available for developers. Once the effect is coded (waaay beyond my abilities) then they are often cross-ported to other formats.

Comment: Thanks. Audio Unit on OS X is what VST is on Windows. I am looking for an OS X complement for the Windows APO technology.

Comment: VST is simply a proprietary plugin format. It is not platform-specific. CoreAudio is the Mac's alternative for providing internal audio processing. It uses AU plugins. That's as close as you're going to get to APO.

Comment: BTW, you haven't actually said what you are trying to achieve, only how you think you might achieve it.

Comment: @Danijel As said, SoundSource by Rogue Amoeba will let you apply effects to system audio or per application. https://rogueamoeba.com/soundsource/